# Can Ionic apps be easily ported as a Web Application?

Tags: javascript, reactive, angular

I am newbie to angular and Ionic world and trying to figure out the right stack to get started with my requirement to develop a hybrid mobile app.

I understand that Ionic is a wrapper around other JSframeworks as well as Angular. My requirement is to build a hybrid app that runs on web as well as Android and iOS. I checked out many examples and scripts where there sre demos for Android and iOS but not for Web.

I suppose there is an option to port Ionic apps as PWA. Is that any tough? Would the plugins and integrations I do for Ionic still valid for my web app?

I have set my mind on using Angular but not sure if I should start with Ionic-Angular.

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ionic app is ported as Web application but it's possible in new ionic version 
(i.e. Ionic-4). Because angular and react are integrate with ionic-4 so we can easily develop the mobile app and web application.